# CSS3 Background Image not going behind body?

Tags: html, image, css, background

I have a background image and when I write it in my body tag the background image works but it overlaps the text on my body. I want to position it behind the body and I tried using `background-position` and it wasn't working. How do I place the background image behind the body so it doesn't overlap?

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #000000;
  box-shadow: #000000;
  background: url(../images/bats.gif) center;
  background-position: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 5px black;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

Comment: may we see some code?

Comment: _“when I write it in my body tag the background image works but it overlaps the text on my body”_ – then you must have messed something up – that is not normal behavior for a background-image (it _is_ in the background, as the name says). Have you maybe most of your content positioned absolutely or something? _“I want to position it behind the body and I tried using background-position and it wasn't working”_ – of course not, because `background-position` is for positioning on the x- and y-axis, not on the z-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it's working (background-image is behind the text) [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kh77B/1/).

**OR**
You can add the background to your html tag.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kh77B/)

```
html
{  
 background: url("paste your image url here");
}
```

Addition: If you want the background-image cover your full screen (browser), you can use background-size: cover;

Good Luck!! (Sorry if this not meets your requirement).